# Android 4.0.4 Webview - html5 video autoplay randomally not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, html5-video

I am using a Webview and have html5 video tag:

```
<video id="video" class="video-full-screen" preload="none"    poster="{poster URL here}" webkit-playsinline>
    <source id="mp4" src="{Video mp4 source here}" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

For autoplay of Android API 17+ I use the `autoplay="autoplay"` attribute on the video tag + I use the `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` (set to false).

For API level below 17 I use:

```
var video = $('video');
video.bind("loadeddata", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       video[0].play();
   },100);
});
```

This works on all devices but Android 4.0.4 (Samsung galaxy s3). On this device it works randomly (I couldn't find any reproduction scenario. It just works randomly). 
I registered to the "playing" event:

```
video.bind("playing", function(){
    console.log("playing");
});
```

and I see that this event is triggered when the video does not play. What I see a grey screen with the player image inside. The current time of the video stays 0 even after few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to override @JavascriptInterface in your java interface method.

So, change your code into

```
 @JavascriptInterface
 video.bind("playing", function(){
 console.log("playing");
 });
```

like this. hope it helps you.

Comment: This code does not do anything (only binding the "playing" event and writes to the log). How can this help???

Comment: did you tried what i shared with you? your function will not invoke until you override this. please add and let me know the result. And this is applicable for 4.3 and above.

Comment: Ok, tnx. I'll try and update. Did you see that my problem is on Android 4.0.4 only?

Comment: the "video.bind("playing", function(){ ..." is written inside the html page. I do not understand what you meant here (your syntax is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

Here the Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/dineshk/fvnr0zex/2/

This is Working fine absolutly Now in My apps.

This Will work when the video tag append using Javascript.

Here the Javascript code

```
 var newHtml = '<video width="100%" height="30%" autoplay controls  id="myVideos" src="https://dev.ocutagsnap.com:8080/PearsonVideos/videos/tumb10.mp4" ></video>';
$("#newone").append(newHtml);
```